# What are the errors on my test?

Tags: unit-test

```
global class BatchDeleteAccounts implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
    global final string query;
    global BatchDeleteAccounts(){
        query = 'SELECT Id,Name FROM Secciones__c WHERE Name = \'Eliminar\'';
    }  
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<sObject> lst){
        Database.delete(lst,false);
    }  
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    }
}
```

## TEST

```
@isTest
public class TestBatchDeleteAccounts
{
    static testMethod void TestBatchDeleteAccounts()
    {

      Test.startTest();
      BatchDeleteAccounts obj = new BatchDeleteAccounts();
       obj.query = 'SELECT Id,Name FROM Secciones__c WHERE Name = \'Eliminar\' Limit 10';



         DataBase.executeBatch(obj,10); 
         Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you are new to unit tests, you should complete the [Salesforce Trailhead modules](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules) and also read [this article](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests)

Answer (score 1):

You need to insert a record first:

```
insert new Secciones__c(Name='Eliminar');
DataBase.executeBatch(obj,10);
```